# Python: calculating difference between rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe listing revenue by company and year. See below:

```
           Company |      Acc_Name  |Date       | Value
               A2M  Sales/Revenue  2016  167770000.0
               A2M  Sales/Revenue  2017  360842000.0
               A2M  Sales/Revenue  2018   68087000.0
               A2M  Sales/Revenue  2019  963000000.0
               A2M  Sales/Revenue  2020  143346000.0
```

In python I want to create a new column showing the difference year on year, so 2017 will show the variance between 2017 & 2016.
I'm wanting to run this on a large dataframe with multiple companies.

Comment: Variance? As in the statistical formula? (For only two points?)

Comment: Variance as in difference between the two numbers. e.g. 2016 revenue minus 2017 revenue.

Comment: Oh, so just the difference then? This is the formula commonly referred to as "variance" https://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/variance.asp

Comment: I see. I have edited to make more accurate

Comment: `dataframe.Value - dataframe.Value.shift(1)`?

Comment: Please tag the library you are using for the dataframe; pandas, pyspark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
revenues['Revenue_Change'] = revenues['Value'].diff(periods=1)
```

Is the simplest way to do it. However, since your dataframe contains data for multiple companies, you can use this:

```
revenues['Revenue_Change'] = revenues.groupby('Company',sort=False)['Value'].diff(periods=1)
```

This sets the first entry for each company in the set to NAN.

If, by any chance, the dataframe is not in order, you can use

```
revenues = revenues.sort_values('Company')
```

Groupby will correctly calculate YoY revenue change, even if entries are separated from one another, as long as the actual revenues are chronologically in order for each company.

EDIT:

If everything is out of order, then sort by the year, groupby and then sort by company name:

```
revenues = revenues.sort_values('Date')
revenues['Revenue_Change'] = revenues.groupby('Company',sort=False)['Value'].diff()    
revenues = revenues.sort_values('Company')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution which creates a new column with previous year data and then simply takes the differences of them:

```
df["prev_val"] = df["Value"].shift(1) # creates new column with previous year data
df["Difference"] = df["Value"] - df["prev_val"]
```

Since you are willing to do this on several companies, make sure that you filter out other companies by

`this_company_df = df[df["Company"] == "A2M"]`

and order data in ascending order by

`this_company_df = this_company_df.sort_values(by=["Date"], ascending=True)`

So, the final code code should look something like this:

```
this_company_df = df[df["Company"] == "A2M"] 
this_company_df = this_company_df.sort_values(by=["Date"], ascending=True)
this_company_df["prev_val"] = this_company_df["Value"].shift(1) 
this_company_df["Difference"] = this_company_df["Value"] - this_company_df["prev_val"]
```

So, the result is stored in `"Difference"` column. One more thing you could improve is to take care of initial year by setting it to 0.